# Clean way to Build concatenated Multiple source Paths and Convert for Cygwin RSync execution to copy specific Hard Linked Folder Trees?

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, cygwin

Clean way to Build concatenated Multiple source Paths & Convert for Cygwin RSync execution to copy specific Hard Linked Folder Trees?

This requires 2 main stages:

- Building the Full Windows Path Strings by setting, using & concat of variables
- Once the paths are built, use Cygwin function **cypath** for conversion of Paths

I've done first stage of this in a Batch File given below. I've also written .SH file but some of my .sh scripting knowledge & syntax is not good, so I'd appreciate if it can be fixed for bugs/ flaws.

And how would I take those first stage Windows path strings and use the Cygwin path conversion function **cypath** to get Full Cygwin Paths, that could be given to Rsync.

You can ignore the ln.exe execution line as that's specific to usage of ln.exe as a tool, and not the same for rsync.

> **Note: Command-line tools for Hard Link preserving Copying:**

- **ln.exe - command line hardlinks** - http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html (Win)
- **Rsync** variations - (Several *Nix & Windows: Cygwin variations, CW RSync, Delta Copy/ Syncrify/ Synaman, GRsync, RsyncBackup, Rsync.exe pkg, Rclone, AcroSync, YInterSync)

**Working .BAT (using LN.exe under Windows)**

```
HL_Copy_LN.BAT

ECHO ON   

REM ### Setting up of NEEDED Variables ###  

REM Setting up the Source Hard Linked Folder tree names
SET FolA1="f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122"
SET FolA2="iMazing.Versions\Versions\f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122"

REM Setting up the Parent Folder for SOURCE folders (Can vary) 
SET SrcRoot="C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\iMazing\Backups"

REM Setting up the GRAND PARENT DESTINATION Folder for Source folders (Can vary) 
SET DstRoot="S:\_HDD_WD750\T61\HL_TEST\LN"

REM Additional info: Count/ Number & Info about variation of arguments used +  Concatenated into Destination PARENT folder & LogFile names (Can vary)
SET DstCountFol="003--includedir--cp-bk"
SET DstLog=%DstCountFol:"=%_Log.txt

REM  ###  Concatenations of Variables  ###  

REM GrandParent Folder + Parent folder name parameters
SET DstPlus=%DstRoot:"=%\%DstCountFol:"=%

REM Concatenate together Paths for Multiple Source Folders to use for HL copy
SET SrcA1=%SrcRoot:"=%\%FolA1:"=%
SET SrcA2=%SrcRoot:"=%\%FolA2:"=%

REM Concatenate together Paths for Multiple DEST Folders to use for HL copy
SET DstA1=%DstRoot:"=%\%DstCountFol:"=%\%FolA1:"=%
SET DstA2=%DstRoot:"=%\%DstCountFol:"=%\%FolA2:"=%

REM Echoing the Source & Dest Paths in Full 
ECHO %SrcA1%
ECHO %SrcA2%

ECHO %DstA1%
ECHO %DstA2%

REM Execute the HL preserving copy of Hard Linked Folder Trees  
ln.exe --progress --json --output %DstLog% --source %SrcA2% --destination %DstA2% --backup --copy %SrcA1% %DstA1%

ECHO ON
```

Ported/ Converted .SH Script

```
HL_Copy_RSync.SH (The needed code - Needs clean up) 

#  ### Setting up of NEEDED Variables ###  

#  Setting up the Source Hard Linked Folder tree names
export  FolA1="f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122"
export  FolA2="iMazing.Versions\Versions\f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122"

#  Setting up the Parent Folder for SOURCE folders (Can vary) 
export  SrcRoot="C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\iMazing\Backups"

#  Setting up the GRAND PARENT DESTINATION Folder for Source folders (Can vary) 
export  DstRoot="S:\_HDD_WD750\T61\HL_TEST\LN"

#  Additional info: Count/ Number & Info about variation of arguments used +  Concatenated into Destination PARENT folder & LogFile names (Can vary)
export  DstCountFol="003--includedir--cp-bk"
export  DstLog=$DstCountFol"_Log.txt"

#   ###  Concatenations of Variables  ###  

#  GrandParent Folder + Parent folder name parameters
export  DstPlus=$DstRoot"\\"$DstCountFol

#  Concatenate together Paths for Multiple Source Folders to use for HL copy
export  SrcA1=$SrcRoot"\\"$FolA1
export  SrcA2=$SrcRoot"\\"$FolA2

#  Concatenate together Paths for Multiple DEST Folders to use for HL copy
export  DstA1=$DstRoot"\\"$DstCountFol"\\"$FolA1
export  DstA2=$DstRoot"\\"$DstCountFol"\\"$FolA2

#  Echoing the Source & Dest Paths in Full 
echo $SrcA1
echo $SrcA2

echo $DstA1
echo $DstA2

# Stage 2 - Use cygpath - to convert Windows Path strings to Full Cygpath Strings
#$CygSrcA1=$(cygpath -u $SrcA1)

echo DstRoot: 

echo $DstRoot
$CygDstRoot=$(cygpath -u $DstRoot)

echo Cyg: 
echo $CygDstRoot

#   ###  Execute the HL preserving copy of Hard Linked Folder Trees  ###  
# ln.exe --progress --json --output $DstLog --source $SrcA2 --destination $DstA2 --backup --copy $SrcA1 $DstA1

# Rsync Execution Syntax 
echo ON
```

---

Output: (My variables & path build/ concatenation here definitely has some mess ups)

```
Ax@MyMachine /cygdrive/c/apps/_ntfs/Scripts
$ bash RS_001.sh
ON
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\iMazing\Backups\f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\iMazing\Backups\iMazing.Versions\Versions\f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122
S:\_HDD_WD750\T61\HL_TEST\LN\003--includedir--cp-bk\f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122
S:\_HDD_WD750\T61\HL_TEST\LN\003--includedir--cp-bk\iMazing.Versions\Versions\f22ebcffcdd1b508d3f7564431a9db98d69208ef-20190414-170122
DstRoot:
S:\_HDD_WD750\T61\HL_TEST\LN
RS_001.sh: line 68: =/cygdrive/s/_HDD_WD750/T61/HL_TEST/LN: No such file or directory
Cyg:

ON
```

Now, its not rocket science to sit and learn the Syntax & format of BASH/ Unix Shell scripts, but given the nuances & intricacies of these instead of posting tons of these issues I'd rather streamline the ask in one go:

- Concatenation / Special Character issues
- Path issues
- EOL / CR-LF issues
- String issues
- Unix vs Windows vs Cygwin issues
- File system issues

I figured I'd put this out with my sample of .BAT & .SH and maybe someone can give a clean way to CONVERT these minimizing these intricate issues.

---

Example of CYGWIN Rsync testing done so far

```
CYGWIN_RSync_Test.SH

# This little sample works directly on Cygwin
SRCDIR="/cygdrive/c/APPS/_NTFS/Scripts/RS /cygdrive/c/APPS/_NTFS/Scripts/TestFol"
DESTDIR="/cygdrive/S/_HDD_WD750/T61/HL_TEST/RS_000"

# rsync -avb "/cygdrive/c/APPS/_NTFS/Scripts/RS" "/cygdrive/S/_HDD_WD750/T61/HL_TEST/RS_002"

rsync -avb  $SRCDIR $DESTDIR


# What would a clean way to setup these Variables, then concatenate & clean/ convert path strings  

# Hard Links Parameters/ Arguments for Rsync
# rsync -ahPruvz --hard-links C S
```

Comment: Updated - I think I found part of the bug & fixed it myself - Now I need to do the cygpath & rysnc

Comment: Update 2 - Concat seems to be working, but CygPath is firing some error

Comment: Way too much. Your Q should focus on one problem, and should be demonstratable with something like `currPath="/.../xjsdlfj/s..fa;lj" ; fixPath=$(cygpath "$currPath"); echo "fixPath=$fixPath`. Keep it simple! and Good luck.

Comment: Oh, and did you know about https://shellcheck.net ? Be sure to include a `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your code when  you paste it in. Again, focus on just the problem area of your script. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - Thank you for the points. I will update the above as I fix it a bit more and "target" the "problem" areas of my script. PS: Did not know about ShellCheck - Try it as we speak - Any other such ones?

Comment: The only other tool website for scripting (bash, cmd) that I know about is is https://batsh.org this helps you convert `.bat` (Windows) to `bash` scripts and visa-versa. There are other resources for `bash` specific, see the lists embedded on the right side of the screen at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98569/bin-bash .